# Can I use a different number of grid columns on the same website using twitter bootstrap?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

As the title says - Can I use a different number of grid columns on the same website using twitter bootstrap?

For example, on the `about page` I would like to define a grid system of 14 elements, but on the `contact page` I would like to use 8 column grid system. Can I do that?

I know there is variable named `@gridColumns` but can I define it for different pages `<div classes>` or is there another way?

Edit:
There is a way to do this by using different layouts and by using different include files - for the former overwriting the css for the `about page`, and in latter a layout to include css for the `contact page`. I think this could be done but is there a better way?

Comment: Hm, nothing that much that could help. I have tried to find where `@gridColumns` are defined in twitter bootstrap, and try to find a way to define it for separate `div`'s . In a way I am suck at the beginning, so in a way I am looking if someone run on this kind of the problem before.

Comment: Other than using different layout for a different page, i dont think there could be any better approach, in this case.

Comment: @prem at the end I have found a little better solution. I think there could be even better, but it works for now. Thanks for looking into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems I have found a way. At least this is one of the ways I am sure. It is working for now, but I will investigate further and if I find a better solution I will post it here.

I have accomplished it by creating a new file in assets - lets say `about.css.less` in my `assets/stylesheets` folder. I have putt all the variables that I wanted to overwrite on `about` page. (Basically I have copied content of `bootstrap_and_overrides.css` and I have overwritten params that I wanted)

And then in `/view/layouts/application.html.erb` I have put code:

```
<% if params[:controller] != 'about' %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
<%end%>
```

And it is now including `abouts.css` for `about` page and all other when it is not. This is at least one solution.

Comment: It is same as "including seperate style file". But, rails will automatically loads the controller names style file, so you don't have to include the file explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for the additional comment. I have updated the answer. Thanks

Comment: No need to put condition like this, you can load controller specific assets in rails as shown here. Ex: You can add <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", controller_name %> for css and <%= javascript_include_tag "application", controller_name %> for js, in your layout file.

Comment: Yes, but this is condition `not` to load other stylesheets. For this solution I don't need to include specific files, but to find the ones that shouldn't be included, as controller specific css will be loaded automatically, like you said. But anyways thanks for the comments and for the help. Bye